# Como utilizar herança em ManagedBeans?

Tags: jsf-2.2, herança

Considerando:

```java
public abstract class Usuario {
    public Usuario(String login, String senha) {
        this.login = login;
        this.senha = senha;
    }
    private String login;
    private String senha;
}
public class Professor extends Usuario {
    public Professor(String login, String senha, String cpf) {
        super(login, senha);
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }
    private String cpf;
}
public class Aluno extends Usuario {
    public Aluno(String login, String senha, String matricula) {
        super(login, senha);
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
    private String matricula;
}
```

Como eu poderia transformar as subclasses acima em `ManagedBeans` e como eu faria para passar os valores vindos da view para os atributos da superclasse? Sei que se colocar apenas a anotação `@ManagedBean` nas subclasses não irá funcionar.

O principal motivo disso é que tanto o professor quanto o aluno irão logar no mesmo formulário e o filtro (`javax.servlet.Filter`) precisa receber um `Usuario` para evitar boilerplates no próprio filtro e nas subclasses, com repetição de atributos.

```java
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
   Usuario u = (Usuario)((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession().getAttribute("usuario");
    if (usuario != null && usuario.isAutorizado()) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    else {
        String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getContextPath();
        ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect(contextPath + "login.jsf");
    }
}
```